# How to display Javadoc with parameter auto-prompt information in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

In Eclipse, when writing code, it prompts for all possible combinations and Javadocs associated with each combination.
However, in Intellij, JavaDocs can only be displayed after all parameters have been entered, and then performing a Control-Q on the method. I can't make Javadocs appear as input like Eclipse.
[***This is a comparison of Eclipse and Intellij***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT3Wd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## New feature, 2018.2

Perhaps you are looking for this new feature to appear in IntelliJ 2018.2. See the [Early Access Program announcement](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/05/intellij-idea-2018-2-early-access-program-is-open/) for more discussion and screenshots.

> The code completion in IntelliJ IDEA continues to evolve, and now the IDE shows both all the possible auto-completions and Javadoc, at the same time (without the need to directly invoke Javadoc each time). Please be aware that you need to actually enable this cool new feature. Go to `Preferences | Editor | General | Code Completion` and turn on the `Show the documentation info pop-up in…` options.

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](https://d3nmt5vlzunoa1.cloudfront.net/idea/files/2018/05/Screen-Shot-2018-05-16-at-19.09.32.png))</sub>

Comment: Great, I just got a latest version of IntelliJ 2018.2 and solved my needs